# Best way to determine if an array is increasing or decreasing

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of values, I want to determine if its an increasing or decreasing array. Of course this is trivial if we want to detect only Monotone Increasing/Decreasing. But if we have an array like this:

3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.3, 3.4, 3.7, 4.2, 4.8

It is indeed an increasing array, but not monotone because for i=3 we have 3.3<3.4

Also, a single check between first and last index is not an option for me, as I may be working with angles, and I could complete more than a single circle:

270º, 290º, 315º, 345º, 5º

I would say that a clockwise is increasing too, despite 5º<270º

Also, if I'm defining angles from 0 to 180 and then -180 to 0 instead of 0 to 360, this is again a problem:

170º, 175º, 180º, -175º, -170º is again increasing for me.

I want to write this for C++, but what matters to me is the algorithm to use. Any idea?

Comment: your definition is quite fuzzy... is `3 3.2 3.4 3.6 0 1 2 3 4` increasing?

Comment: Isn't increasing just "monotonically" increasing? Is there any cyclic case where the array cannot be treated as increasing?

Comment: For clarity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: "monotonic (also monotonically increasing, increasing or non-decreasing)" said Wikipedia.

Comment: Ok, mathematically speaking "increasing" is the same as "monotonic increasing", but in a real system you can have some measurements errors so, when you have an array such as 3 3.2 3.4 3.3 3.6... you would say it's indeed increasing. But an strict algorithm would say it is not. That's what I'm asking for

Comment: @RomanRdgz: But then could you just add `[1, 2, ..] * lengthOfCycle` to each of the element thus render all cyclic cases increasing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Based on the resulting slope you can decide whether it's increasing or decreasing.

[image: linear regression example from wikipedia]

As for the cyclic case: I would simply move the "negative" elements in front of the list and then do the test...

Note: for special cases like `5 4 3 2 1 1000` this will still tell you that it's increasing, but it's hard to give an exact answer for your question as the definition of "increasing" is quite fuzzy. (You might want to filter out some crazy values?)

Another simple approach would be to count the number of increases and decreases between adjacent elements, but in this case `10 11 12 13 14 0 1 2 3 4` would be clearly increasing (which might be the right answer, it's hard to tell..)

Without knowing more of what you're trying to achieve it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Ok, and then I should be checking only if the slope is >0 or <0, right?

Comment: yes.. but first you have to decide whether this fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in python:

```
def angles_are_increasing(a):
    first=a[0]
    value=first
    previous=first
    for current in a:
        delta=current-previous
        if delta<180:
            delta+=360
        elif delta>180:
            delta-=360
        value+=delta
        previous=current
    last=value
    return last>first
```

The idea is to smooth out the jumps when the angles wrap back around, such as treating 345,5 as 345,365.  If you do this as you go, you can then compare your final value to the first value to see whether the values have been generally increasing.